# Asp.Net program

Tags: c#, asp.net

What does the following line of code do

```
SqlDataSource DataSource =(SqlDataSource)CreateUserWizardStep1.
ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("InsertExtraInfo");
```

Answer (score 4):

MSDN can tell you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx

It will find the control that is a child of `ContentTemplateContainer`, with the ID of `InsertExtraInfo`, and then cast it to `SqlDataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

It simply says: "It uses FindControl to get the SqlDataSource then bind it to CreateUserWizard".